# How to cache top N posts ordered by rating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rails-api

I'm writing a Rails 5 JSON API.

I've got an action that returns **top *N* blog posts** based on *average rating*. In order to achieve low response time, I denormalized my database such that `posts` has a `average_rating` column.

I'm also *caching* every query like so:

```
# posts_controller.rb
def top
  quantity = params[:quantity]

  if quantity.to_i > 0
    render json: {
      posts: cached_top_posts(quantity)
    }, status: :ok
  else
    render json: '', status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def cached_top_posts(quantity)
  Rails.cache.fetch(['top', quantity], expires_in: 1.hour) do
    Post.limit(quantity).as_json(only: [:title, :content, :average_rating])
  end
end
```

(Order by `average_rating` is in the model itself)

I am aware that this is far from optimal.

Whilst it drastically improves response time when requesting the same quantity of posts, it would be much better if, when it already **cached top 1000 posts**, it will not **cache 100 posts**, but instead would get **first 100 posts** out of the **cached 1000**.

What is a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after I had a good night's sleep, a simple conclusion just came into my mind.

Here it is:

```
# posts_controller.rb
def cached_top_posts(quantity)
  data = Rails.cache.read('top_posts')
  if data.nil? || data[:quantity] < quantity
    data = {
      :quantity => quantity,
      :posts => Post.limit(quantity).as_json(only: [:title, :content, :average_rating])
    }
    Rails.cache.write('top_posts', data, expires_in: 1.hour)
  end
  data[:posts][0...quantity]
end
```